# Something is wrong in this if else statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

When I print the content of the message, it always gives me "underweight" although displaybmi is not <19

```
public String BMImessage(){
    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String Height = customSharedPreference.getString("heightpref", "");
    String Weight = customSharedPreference.getString("weightpref", "");

    float weight = Float.valueOf(Weight);
    float height = Float.valueOf(Height);

    float displaybmi = weight/(height*height);
    if (displaybmi <19) 
        message = "Underweight" ;
    else if (displaybmi >=19 && displaybmi <=25) 
        message = "Desirable Weight";
    else if (displaybmi >=26 && displaybmi <=29) 
        message =  "Overweight" ;
    else if (displaybmi >=30 && displaybmi <=40) 
        message =  "Obese";
    else if (displaybmi >40) 
        message = "Extremely Obese" ;
    return message;
}
```

Comment: I'm betting that displaybmi is < 19, because it's more likely that the type conversion or math is wrong that that the comparison operator is.  Have you checked that height and weight are getting set correctly from the prefs?

Comment: Try to print the value of the expression before the if.

Comment: What happens if `displaybmi == 25.5`? Then none of strings is selected. Also, where is the variable `message` defined?

Comment: `message` is not declared locally within the function. I'll bet you're not actually using the return value from this function, or perhaps you're changing the value somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks thomas, I had a mistake in displaybmi, if you can put your comment as an answer, i would be glad to check it as a solution.

Comment: if you are doing this in pounds and inches the result needs to be multiplied by 703

Comment: I would also recommend having a simple `else` section as well

Comment: Obligatory floating point arithmetic reference http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Your best bet would be to either gain some weight, or turn on the debugger and debug this simple method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also double check your calculations:

```
float displaybmi = weight/(height*height);
```

This works if your weight is in Kilograms and the height is in Meters. If your weight is in pounds and the height in inches you need to add the conversion factor:

```
float displaybmi = (weight * 703.0)/(height * height);
```

[Calculate-Your-Body-Mass-Index](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Your-Body-Mass-Index-%28BMI%29)

Answer (score 3):

What *is* the value of displaybmi?  Try changing the comparison to use `19.0` to ensure that no truncation is happening.  You're comparing a `float` (displaybmi) to an `int` (19) which can result in undesired behavior.

Comment: I wonder how comparing float to an int can be an issue. Obviously a widening primitive type conversion will be applied.

Comment: @Martin There's no guarantee that `19.0` or any other whole integer can be represented exactly. So depending on the rounding the integer `X` may be smaller, equal or larger than  `(float)X`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two floats, the you can use `Float.compare(float f1, float f2)`

```
if (Float.compare(displaybmi, 19) < 0) 
    message = "Underweight" ;
else if (Float.compare(displaybmi, 19) >= 0 && Float.compare(displaybmi, 25) <= 0)
...
```

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare%28float,%20float%29) says:

> Compares two Float objects numerically. There are two ways in which
>   comparisons performed by this method differ from those performed by
>   the Java language numerical comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`)
>   when applied to primitive float values:
>
> - `Float.NaN` is considered by
>     this method to be equal to itself and greater than all other float
>     values (including Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY).
> - `0.0f` is considered by this method to be greater than `-0.0f`. This ensures that the natural ordering of Float objects imposed by this
>     method is consistent with equals.